# Extending additional formatting option in MS Access 2000

Tags: ms-access

Here is the scenario, I need to come-up a grid in MS Access that will display data/records that have a colored background, let say, if I have a data that pertains to closed issue, it will be red, completed will be green and on the process will be yellow. What will I do if a record/s is critical and needs to be marked as blue. The only problem that I have right now is that MS Access 2000 has only three (3) conditional formatting option. What will I do to extend it to four (4)? Does anyone out there have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

[Extending the Functionality of Conditional Formatting in Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139965%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I've seen this one when I searched in Google. Need to know if Access can have an option of more than three (3).

Comment: yuor question states you only need 3 values!